# Designer "errors" and the Assembly Binding Log Viewer (Fuslogvw.exe)

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, windows-forms-designer

I have a form that does not open in designer displaying:
[image]

I [heard](http://www.purelogic.ca/blog/matt/2010/10/13/visual-studio-2010-designer-exception-unresolvedassemblyexception.aspx) that the Assembly Binding Log Viewer (Fuslogvw.exe) could be useful...

When I launched that tool, I had any log inside... I reopened the "buggy" form in the Designer but nothing reflected in the Log Viewer.
[image]
How can I use it?